# Abstract WordSpec test

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a abstract base class, says

```
abstract class A {
  def abstractMethod(a: String): String
  def concreteMethod(a: String): String = s"$a + 1"
}
```

so I think I would be nice if we can inherit and/or override WordSpec test define in parent class, so sub class test does not need to reimplement all the tests.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying you inherit the tests or simply some utility methods? Inheriting tests does not make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, it is about inheritance. I was using JUnit and we can save a pretty much time reusing code like that, e.g. you have an `AbstractRepository` with some base operation you can write template behavior and let the `ConcreateRepository` define the `Entity`